# amount of video on iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad

If I am not wrong, Apple imposes a limit of 200 mb on the size applications can have. I am planning to include some videos in one of my apps and the videos include several large segments of 10 or 20 minutes.

If I encode these videos for ipad (720p) and for iPhone 4 (1024x768) do you guys have an idea of how much space a minute using one of these encodings will consume?

In other words: how many minutes will I be able to store in (lets say) 190 MB for iPad and for iPhone 4?

on the iPhone 4 I have to consider the case of packing the application with both formats (3GS/3G - 480x320) and iphone 4 (1024x768).

Consider two apps: one for iPad and another one for iPhone.

thanks.

Comment: I don't know where you heard 200MB limit, but one app I downloaded was about 2.1 GB.

Comment: At 720p, 190mb doesn't give you much.  Typically, they say anything over 1mb/s bitrate is getting into HD (with most doing 3mb/s for 720p) so you do the math :)  You might find some better info on the `Handbrake` forums since those guys are video gurus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that limit is true, conservatively, it looks like at least [8-10 minutes](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1399755) for the iPhone 4 display, and you could scale up that calculation for the iPad.

Comment: given that the assumed limit was show to be incorrect and that this answer was not the first - I have to ask: was it accepted because Alex has more rep points than myself or Tammen (who has a more upvoted answer)?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, applications have a maximum size of 2gb (rather than 200mb). If the app exceeds 20 mb then the app is not available for download over 3G etc and you are stuck with wifi only.

If possible, I would advise keeping your app as small as possible and hosting the video on a server. This may not be applicable for your situation, but if you have an app in the 100's of mb your users are going to have a painful download experience, but more personally you are going to have to upload the same massive file for updates/slight bug fixes.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the 200MB limit you're referring to. Under the iTunesConnect Developer PDF it lists a 2GB limit.

In reference to the OTA downloads (3G, EDGE) AT&T/Apple limits the app to be under 10MB. I'm not sure if other carriers have different caps on app sizes for OTA downloads.

The policy (or reference) for the 2GB limit for an application that can be submitted to the App Store can be found under the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide PDF](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (page 57, section B under the Application section).